# How to display the value of a php variable by clicking on a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to display the balance of the user when he clicks on the hyperlink. the balance of the user is stored in a php variable. I am hoping that this can be done using javascript but I dont have much experience in javascript.

Below is my code:

```
$userbalance = $xyz[2];
echo "Your balance stands at  ".$xyz[2];
```

This thing is working, but I want to display `$userbalance` by clicking on a link

I don't know what to put in the anchor tag.

Is it possible that by clicking on the  hyperlink the value of the php varibale gets displayed?

Can I pass a function to `href`? or can I use `onclick` in some way?

Comment: So what you want is to display your sentence only when the user clicks on a specific route, then point the href link to this route.

Comment: You need javascript for that, php is a server side language. Either `onclick` or add a listener

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="somepage.php?balance=<?php $balance = $xyz[2]; echo "Your balance stands at  ". $balance; ?>" >Click</a>
```

By above method you can display balance in url at any pages. Then if you need to use that balance there just get that value with super global variable `$_GET['balance'];`

Answer (score 0):

**In the most simplest form**, this can be done via storing the value in the "data-" attribute that HTML supports and then using Javascript to alert the value upon user's click.

```
<p>
  Click to see your account
  <a href="javascript:void();" data-balance="123 €" onclick="window.alert(this.getAttribute('data-balance'))">balance</a>.
</p>
```

The PHP part of this would be just to echo the correct balance into the correct place in the HTML code above.

```
<a href="javascript:void();" data-balance="<?= $balance ?>" onclick="window.alert(this.getAttribute('data-balance'))">balance</a>.
```

Example of the final HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/oh8jnmg2/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution if you don't want to actually use two pages but still show new content and hide everything else:

```
$userbalance = $xyz[2];
echo `Your balance stands at <a href='javascript:{document.documentElement.innerHTML = ""; document.write(` . $xyz[2] . `);}'>see variable</a>`;
```

If you want just to display a new value below, then use:

```
$userbalance = $xyz[2];
echo `Your balance stands at <div id="myDiv"><a href='javascript:{document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = ` . $xyz[2] . `;}'>see variable</a></div>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Niltish has given the right hint. But I wouldn't recommend putting a output string into a link, which gets displayed in the url. Since HTML is rendered through PHP, you can simply attach your value to the link by typing:

```
<a href="yourprintsite.php?balance=$userbalance>Click here to see your balance</a>
```

And then on yourprintsite.php, you just type:

```
if (!empty($_GET['balance')) {
  echo "Your balance stands at " . $_GET['balance'];
}
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can write next code, function getAttribute must you help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickHanler(d){
       alert(d.getAttribute("data-userbalance"));
    }
</script>

<a
   data-userbalance="21" 
   href="#" 
   onclick="clickHanler(this);">
        Click to do something
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with the **HTML**, you need to create a `<a></a>` that routes to no where :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="linktobalance">Click to see Balance</a>
```

Then, in the **Javascript** part :

1. We will assign a method to handle the click on our link.
2. we need to use an [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to get the `balance` from the `balance.php` page :

   ```
   $("#linktobalance").on("click", function(){
       $.post( "balance.php", function(balance) {
         //In this part, the balance is the value returned from th PHP, you can do whatever with it, I'll alert it
         alert( "The user balance is "+balance );
       });
   });
   ```

**Note** : we used [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), you can add it to your project by doing this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#showbalance").click(function(){
    $("#balance").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="showbalance">Show Balance</a>
<div id="balance" style="display: none;">
   Balance = 1000   
</div>
```